# Alert Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on google apps script. I would like to send alert message (kind of browser.msg) to another spreadsheet i have just created before with my script. But impossible to push browser.msg() or getui() in another spreadsheet from my master spreadsheet.

Impossible to find an answer on the web ... Could you help me ?

Thks,

Loic

My unworkable script :

ssp = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file_Id[counter])
ssp.getUi().alert("hola")

Comment: What do you mean by push msg in another spreadsheet?  Are both spreadsheets open, and visible?  `UI` is a user interface for the curently active spreadsheet.

Comment: `A script can only interact with the UI for the current instance of an open spreadsheet, and only if the script is bound to the spreadsheet.` [doc Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getui). It is initiated by `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` - there is no option to reference a specific sheet (such as one opened by ID or URL). It simply runs on the bound spreadsheet.

Comment: Thks for your answers ! 

I have one master spreadsheet which allow me to create 3 others spreadsheets and i would like to send to this spreadsheets alerts when i click on one button of my master spreadsheet. Do you know if there is another way ?